# Accidentally sourced .bash_history

Tags: bash

In a moment of brilliance, I executed the command `source ~/.bash_history`. Fortunately, most of the commands are using `vim` to edit some file, but there are some scary commands in my history - moving and removing files with relative paths.

Fortunately right now it's stuck in a `vim` session, however if I suspend or quit it, it's on to the next one. The history file is 1000 lines long.

How can I cancel this command, short of rebooting the machine?

Comment: This is madness! :)

Comment: madness ? This is sparta!  -- wait, sorry.

Comment: I am not alone :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If it's a local machine, start a new terminal and kill the shell in question.

If it's a remote machine, ssh in and kill the shell in question.

Answer (score 15):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or start a subshell using `:!bash`, and then kill the shell.  Specific steps:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
>   `kill -9 $$`

`:suspend` (or acceptable abbreviations thereof) may function equivalently to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: But if you `:!bash`, then `$$` will refer to the subshell you just created.  You’d need to use `ps` to find out the PID.        ...        P.S. I guess this is, to an extent, a question of style, but if there’s no need to do bash-fancy stuff, I would use just plain `:!sh`.  Also, for that matter, try `:sh`.

Comment: Downvoting because, as the comment points out, as written this might give someone just enough false confidence to exit vim and hose their machine.